# Are empty overridden methods a sign of bad interface design?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I was wondering if **empty overridden methods inherited from an abstract interface class are a sign of bad interface design**. Sometimes interfaces contain methods that are useful only partially for all the possible implemention classes; in the classes where unused methods are not necessary, they are just left empty.

In the following example, `connect()` and `disconnect()` are common to the two implementation classes `IpConnection` and `SmtpConnection`. However, `prepare()` is not necessary in `SmtpConnection` and is left empty.

In this kind of situations, is it better to remove `prepare()` from the abstract interface `IConnection` and call it explicitly, or leave it empty? What if empty (unused) methods grow more and more?

```
#include <memory>

class IConnection
{
public:
    virtual void connect() = 0;    /* common */
    virtual void disconnect() = 0; /* common */
    virtual void prepare() = 0;    /* partial */
};

class IpConnection : public IConnection
{
public:
    void connect()    override { /* ... */ }
    void disconnect() override { /* ... */ }
    void prepare()    override { /* ... */ }
};

class SmtpConnection : public IConnection
{
public:
    void connect()    override { /* ... */ }
    void disconnect() override { /* ... */ }
    void prepare()    override { } /* empty */
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<IConnection> connection;

    connection = std::make_unique<SmtpConnection>();
    connection->connect();
    connection->prepare();
    connection->disconnect();
}
```

Comment: This is merely my personal 2 cents, but if the implementation of something is optional, I usually declare it as empty on the top level instead of purely abstract like in this example. Putting it into the child class forces you to do casting, which should be avoided as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Questions about coding style etc. that are a matter of opinion are considered off-topic here.

Comment: First of all, welcome to the StackOverflow :)

If your interface includes methods that you will not use then you can declare that methods either `protected` or `private` to prevent calling them outside of your class.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a type of 'contract' between two modules. Typically, an interface specifies how another module is allowed to make use of the functionality of the implementing module instance.

So in fact the interface has no business with the implementation itself. It just sets out the rules, possibly some induced flow constraints and protection provisions that any implementation must adhere to in order to provide a functional implementation.

So, if the interface needs to be overriden with an empty body, that' is totally fine. Other implementations may very well need to do work. Of course if you *know* that that is *never* going to happen, well perhaps is better not to over-design at that point, and just remove the interface call.

In your case I would not worry too much and leave it as an interface. Calling functionality directly makes sense ONLY if the overriding method is quite specific to the flow of that implementation, and less useful for other implementations to worry about.

Comment: Don't agree, it's a lot of boilerplate code!